# The history of partial differential equations in the 19th century belongs to applied or pure mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations, math-history, applications

I have been asked to write an essay with the title "The history of partial differential equations in the 19th century belongs to applied mathematics, not pure mathematics. To what extent do you agree, and why?"

Just wondering if anyone had any opinions or good sources to start with?

Comment: "Heat" equation and "wave" equation are not just random names...

Comment: I think the strong distinction between applied and pure maths is more modern than the invention of partial differential equations. Riemann, an archetype pure mathematician of the 19th century, wrote a treatise on Partial Differential Equations in 1882, that is heavily weighted to applied applications.

Comment: I would say that pure Math started with Cantor's set axioms in the late 19th century, and the first rigorous definition of a real number after 24 centuries of searching for such a definition. And most of this was driven by solving concrete problems of Math, especially Fourier series and other techniques of PDEs and ODEs.

Comment: Sorry I should have said that Riemann's lectures on partial differential equations were posthumously published in 1882.

Comment: Up until the late 19th century, mathematics and applied mathematics (physics, especially) were basically indistinguishable.